# Form within a form solutions

Tags: php, html, jquery

I understand that we can't have a form within a form but I have a situation:

I'm using a third-party multi-step form that has each step wrapped in a form attribute.

For example:

```
      <form class="wizard-pane" id="wizard-account">
             Step 1
             do stuff
      </form>

      <form class="wizard-pane" id="wizard-users">
             Step 2
             do stuff
      </form>
```

I tried changing the form to a div but it causes conflicts with the multi-form script.

I need all input fields from each step so that I can save them to a table.

My current solution is to have another group of input fields and then use jquery to pass the values but this is becoming time-consuming.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  
    $('#first_form_field_1').bind('keypress blur keyup keydown change click', function() {
        $('#duplicate_form_field_1').val($(this).val());
    });

});

</script>
```

I also tried using the HTML5 input element's form attribute but this doesnt work because the input fields are wrapped in another form:

```
<form id="first_step">

<input type="text" id="current_serial[]" name="current_serial[]" form="therealdata">

</form>


<form id="therealdata">

 data

</form
```

Comment: Normally the idea with a multi-step wizard is that you save the data from each step separately, at the time the user completes it (probably via an AJAX request). So if you follow that standard approach you don't need an outer form.

Comment: I'm confused about the relationship between your server/database and the third party's multistep form. Is the third party stuff just the visual portion, or are they processing the form, too. Are you trying to keep a duplicate copy for your records?

Comment: @ADyson ah i see, makes sense. I usually do everything at the end.

Comment: @Youngbuck2 That has an unfortunate side effect of the user losing all of the information they have filled out if they for some reason have to reload the page, and there is no way for them to go back and do it later.